# Samsung Series 7 backlit keyboard issue on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, backlight

I upgraded to Windows 8 and the keyboard back-light doesn't work. The mode of the laptop is np700z7c-s02uk

Answer (score 0):

A forum [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/backlit-keyboard-issue-with-windows-8-pro/e29fa473-1fdd-42ea-9a85-a58527a7756b) states that some people had this problem fixed by applying a firmware update, through the Samsung Software Update utility.

Whether this works or not, I don't know for certain as I don't have that model of laptop. Downloads for your machine are [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP700Z7C-S02UK).

If this doesn't work, there is not a lot that can be suggested as this will be handled by Samsung hardware, rather than any particular generic issue. It may be worth contacting Samsung directly regarding this.